# Receive from UART on Pi

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, uart

I'm new here.

I'm trying receive data from UART which is from Xbee.

The sample code below is allow me to check the API frame.

But what I need is make these to be a useful array.

How should i make this into a complete array?

The result shows what i need but they are independent.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <unistd.h>         //Used for UART
#include <fcntl.h>          //Used for UART
#include <termios.h>        //Used for UART

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    //-------------------------
    //----- SETUP USART 0 -----
    //-------------------------
    //At bootup, pins 8 and 10 are already set to UART0_TXD, UART0_RXD (ie the         alt0 function) respectively
    int uart0_filestream = -1;

    //OPEN THE UART
    //The flags (defined in fcntl.h):
    //  Access modes (use 1 of these):
    //      O_RDONLY - Open for reading only.
    //      O_RDWR - Open for reading and writing.
    //      O_WRONLY - Open for writing only.
    //
    //  O_NDELAY / O_NONBLOCK (same function) - Enables nonblocking mode. When set read requests on the file can return immediately with a failure status
    //                                          if there is no input immediately available (instead of blocking). Likewise, write requests can also return
    //                                          immediately with a failure status if the output can't be written immediately.
    //
    //  O_NOCTTY - When set and path identifies a terminal device, open() shall not cause the terminal device to become the controlling terminal for the process.
    uart0_filestream = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);        //Open in non blocking read/write mode
    if (uart0_filestream == -1)
    {
        //ERROR - CAN'T OPEN SERIAL PORT
        printf("Error - Unable to open UART.  Ensure it is not in use by another application\n");
    }


    struct termios options;
    tcgetattr(uart0_filestream, &options);
    options.c_cflag = B9600 | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;     //<Set baud rate
    options.c_iflag = IGNPAR;
    options.c_oflag = 0;
    options.c_lflag = 0;
    tcflush(uart0_filestream, TCIFLUSH);
    tcsetattr(uart0_filestream, TCSANOW, &options);


    //----- TX BYTES -----
    unsigned char tx_buffer[20];
    unsigned char *p_tx_buffer;

    p_tx_buffer = &tx_buffer[0];
    *p_tx_buffer++ = 'H';
    *p_tx_buffer++ = 'e';
    *p_tx_buffer++ = 'l';
    *p_tx_buffer++ = 'l';
    *p_tx_buffer++ = 'o';

    if (uart0_filestream != -1)
    {
        int count = write(uart0_filestream, &tx_buffer[0], (p_tx_buffer -               &tx_buffer[0]));        
    //Filestream, bytes to write, number of bytes to write
        if (count < 0)
        {
            printf("UART TX error\n");
        }
    }   
    char r[100];
    while(1){
        //----- CHECK FOR ANY RX BYTES -----
        if (uart0_filestream != -1)
        {
            //printf("OK");
            // Read up to 255 characters from the port if they are there
            unsigned char rx_buffer[256];
            int rx_length = read(uart0_filestream, (void*)rx_buffer, 255);      //Filestream, buffer to store in, number of bytes to read (max)
            if (rx_length < 0)
            {
                //An error occured (will occur if there are no bytes)

            }
            else if (rx_length == 0)
            {
                //No data waiting       
            }
            else
            {

        //Bytes received
              rx_buffer[rx_length] = '\0';
                printf("%i bytes read : %s\n", rx_length, rx_buffer);

        //printf("%d\n",rx_buffer[0]);

            }

        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

[image: the compile result]

Comment: Note: `if (uart0_filestream != -1)` :: you already checked that after`open()`

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on `The result shows what i need but they are independent.` Do you need to combine different values like `48.02` in a separate array ??

Comment: `How should i make this into a complete array?` Buffer it: when you recieve a character, put it in a buffer, and remember how many chars you have received. when you are done (probably after reception of a '\n' or '\0') your buffered data is complete.

Comment: @Ayush yes,i will need to combine some values from these data,also include the address . The complete frame will be like this: http://imgur.com/46WLkbx

Comment: As I said: **buffer it**. The buffering should be independent of the protocol. In fact, in your case, the buffering *layer* only needs the first three bytes to know when a *frame* is complete.

Comment: @Ayush what if I want to see the frame in hex? I change the printf("%i bytes read : %s\n", rx_length, rx_buffer);  in to %x , but the result turn in http://imgur.com/MX9y5aJ